# android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am begineer in android and having problems
Above error showing while i'm trying to open main activity from login button on login activity.

when pressing the login button suddenly app stops and following error is showing

following error is showing in android monitor

```
10-20 18:47:23.314 13432-13432/com.antherx.prasenjit.ihdfbachatgat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.antherx.prasenjit.ihdfbachatgat, PID: 13432
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.antherx.prasenjit.ihdfbachatgat/com.antherx.prasenjit.ihdfbachatgat.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2460)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2629)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:182)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5706)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1033)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828)
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:132)
     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:77)
     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:4358)
     at com.antherx.prasenjit.ihdfbachatgat.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:26)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1071)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2437)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2629) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:182) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5706) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1033) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828)
```

this is login activity code is their any problem in this code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    //Please do not

    Email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    Password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    String wel_on_login = "Welcome On IHDF Bachat Gat app";
    Toast welcome = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),wel_on_login,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    welcome.show();

    final Button signIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
    final Button register = (Button)findViewById(R.id.registration) ;
    final Intent main_trans = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    final Intent reg_trans = new Intent(this, register.class);

    signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            startActivity(main_trans);
        }
    });

    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(reg_trans);
        }
    });
```

this is main activity codes is their any problem in here

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.home_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    newMember = (MenuItem)findViewById(R.id.new_member);
    newProfile = (MenuItem)findViewById(R.id.profile) ;

    Drawer =(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    sToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,Drawer,R.string.open,R.string.close);


    Grp_ico = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.grp_ico);

    Drawer.addDrawerListener(sToggle);
    sToggle.syncState();

    getSupportActionBar();


    String wel_on_main = "You are successfully on Main Home";
    Toast welcome = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),wel_on_main,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    welcome.show();




}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.new_member :
            startActivity(new_new_member);
        case R.id.profile :
            startActivity(new_new_profile);
        case R.id.setting :
            startActivity(new_new_setting);
        case R.id.meeting :
            startActivity(new_new_meeting);
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


    }

}
```

Comment: Yet another premature Context usage ... obviously you cannot use Context in field initializers

Comment: Paste all code from MainActivity.class, or what is in 26 line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for me i was trying to use the application with no base context accidently.

so i had in my application override:

```
@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
}

//instead of calling its super:

 @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(newBase);}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your `getApplicationContext()` from

`Toast welcome = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),wel_on_main,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);`

to either `getBaseContext()` or preferably `this`

Comment: `...MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:26)` obviously this is not an issue

Comment: He has some field like  `Intent intent = new Intent(this, Some.class);` in MainAcitivty class ... `<init>` means field initializer